# As-Extensions gem is deprecated and crashes with Rails 3.2 update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been struggling for a couple of days on this one. I have upgraded my app from Rails 3.1 to 3.2, and the development server (thin or webrick) has had a memory leak ever since. I cannot even get the localhost root. Here's my Gemfile :

```
gem 'rails', '= 3.2.0'
gem 'thin'
gem "rmagick"
gem "carrierwave"
gem 'rake', '0.9.2'
gem 'fog'
gem 'twitphoto', :git => 'git://github.com/pefavre/twitphoto.git'
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0'
gem 'faker', '0.3.1'
gem 'geocoder'
gem 'map'
gem 'must_be'
gem 'twitter', :git => 'git://github.com/pefavre/twitter.git'
gem 'httparty'
gem 'rest-client'
gem 'foreman'
gem "as-extensions"
gem 'json'
gem 'oauth'
gem 'topsy', :git => 'git://github.com/pefavre/topsy.git'
gem 'gmaps4rails'
gem 'depq'
gem 'newrelic_rpm'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'pg'

group :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.6.1'
  gem 'annotate', '2.4.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.6.1'
  gem 'webrat', '0.7.1'
  gem 'spork', '0.9.0.rc8'
end

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier',     '>= 1.0.3'
end
```

Did I miss something in the upgrade?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean you cannot get the root?  Also, some sort of log extract would be helpful.

Comment: I have no logs because basically nothing happens. The GET localhost request is sent and nothing moves.

Comment: OK problem spotted: I have tested each gem and found that "as-extensions" is responsible of the bug.

Comment: I hereby classify myself as a cardboard cut-out - glad you solved it ;)

Comment: You then might want to delete the question or rephrase it and answer it yourself so it will help people :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the "as-extensions" gem is responsible for the bug. It crashes when Rails is updated from 3.1 to 3.2.